# PHP: can't login with admin account

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to find the data stored in the column 'Nume' based on the 'CNP' and 'Parola' provided with this query:

```html
$query2=mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Nume FROM allusers WHERE CNP='".$cnp." AND Parola='".$pass."'");
```

then store the data found and compare it to see if the admin is trying to log in or just a basic user:

```html
$name=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$admin='Admin';
if($admin===$name)
{
 $_SESSION['sesiune']=$cnp;  
 header("Location: admin_account.php");  
}
else
{
 $_SESSION['sesiune']=$cnp;  
 header("Location: user_account.php"); 
}
```

The if statement is false when I'm using the admin 'CNP' and 'Parola' and I can't login with the admin account, it's just taking me to the user account 
(from the else statement).

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You have to double check your query to check value $cnp is not wrapped by single quote.
Please check my below query for your correction in your query.
`$query2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT Nume FROM allusers WHERE CNP='" . $cnp . "' AND Parola='" . $pass . "'");
`

Comment: Thank you! It was such a small error I didn't see it

Comment: Welcome, You can up vote to comment if you think you get some help from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_assoc` returns an array, so you must use :

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
$admin = 'Admin';
if($admin === $row['Nume'])
{
....
```

Answer (score 0):

After this line

```
$name=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2);
```

Do

```
print_r($name);
```

It will tell you that $name is an array not a string.
Form what i understand you have to do this

```
if($name['numa'] =='Admin')
```